# CentOS : Is it possible to take screenshot in command line from another tty

Tags: centos, screenshot, tty

I am using centOS 7. Let's say I am in tty2 in a terminal. I want to screenshot via a command line what's going on in tty1. Is it possible and if yes how ?

Comment: Is tty1 running Xorg graphics, or is it just a plain text console?

Comment: A screenshot is for something that is visible. Is that the case?

Comment: on tty1 xvfb helps me display the graphical interface of a program run by a docker container.

Answer (score 2):

**Graphics mode:**

It seems that this is not possible in a generic manner, as the kernel doesn't keep individual framebuffers per virtual console, the compositor (Xorg/Wayland) directly takes over the actual GPU outputs. When you switch away, it's not kept in kernel memory.

In X11, you *may* get some results by using CLI screenshot tools, e.g. *maim* – but it seems that they won't work with window managers which use 3D accelerated compositing (such as gnome-shell), because the screen contents are completely unloaded on VT switch.

**Text mode:**

You can use [peekvc](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/peekvc/) to dump another virtual console's contents as ANSI text.

Virtual console contents are directly accessible through `/dev/vcs#` and `/dev/vcsa#` files (the former containing just plain text, the latter containing formatting attributes as well).

Note that this isn't a recommended method for live monitoring. If you want the same program to be continuously running on multiple consoles, you should use a terminal multiplexer such as `tmux` or `screen` or `abduco` which lets you "attach" to the same session.